# Claim Management best practise for user edit page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have managed to get claims working and it works well but I would like to extend the cliams table to have controller and area also I want to display the roles in an edit page which check boxes.

At Present my claims permissions are as follows.

[image]

I no I can get all the permissions per role via this way

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string roleId)
{
  var model = new PermissionViewModel();
  var allPermissions = new List<RoleClaimsViewModel>();
      allPermissions.GetPermissions(typeof(Permissions.Products), roleId);
      var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);
      model.RoleId = roleId;
      var claims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
      var allClaimValues = allPermissions.Select(a => a.Value).ToList();
      var roleClaimValues = claims.Select(a => a.Value).ToList();
      var authorizedClaims = allClaimValues.Intersect(roleClaimValues).ToList();
      foreach (var permission in allPermissions)
      {
            if (authorizedClaims.Any(a => a == permission.Value))
            {
                permission.Selected = true;
            }
        }
        model.RoleClaims = allPermissions;
        return View(model);
      }
```

So my two questions are how does one extend the role claims table and how does one provide an edit page that the user can change the claims. Is their any best practises for an edit page for claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does one extend the role claims table and how does one provide an
> edit page that the user can change the claims.

To extend the role claims table, it is like to extend the `AspNetUser` table. You should inherit from `IdentityRoleClaim`.

Code like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserClaim> Claims { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserLogin> Logins { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserToken> Tokens { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationRoleClaim> RoleClaims { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<string>
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserToken : IdentityUserToken<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

DBcontext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, 
    ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserLogin,
    ApplicationRoleClaim, ApplicationUserToken>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
        {
            // Each User can have many UserClaims
            b.HasMany(e => e.Claims)
                .WithOne(e => e.User)
                .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId)
                .IsRequired();

            // Each User can have many UserLogins
            b.HasMany(e => e.Logins)
                .WithOne(e => e.User)
                .HasForeignKey(ul => ul.UserId)
                .IsRequired();

            // Each User can have many UserTokens
            b.HasMany(e => e.Tokens)
                .WithOne(e => e.User)
                .HasForeignKey(ut => ut.UserId)
                .IsRequired();

            // Each User can have many entries in the UserRole join table
            b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
                .WithOne(e => e.User)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(b =>
        {
            // Each Role can have many entries in the UserRole join table
            b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
                .WithOne(e => e.Role)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();

            // Each Role can have many associated RoleClaims
            b.HasMany(e => e.RoleClaims)
                .WithOne(e => e.Role)
                .HasForeignKey(rc => rc.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();
        });
    }
}
```

Then, you could execute the migration commands to update the database. After that, you could access the `AspNetRole` and `AspNetRoleClaim` table via the `ApplicationDbContext` and the `ApplicationRole` and `ApplicationRoleClaim` model. More detail information, refer [Customize the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0#customize-the-model).

Comment: Thanks for the example how does one then access those custom properties through the AddClaimAysnc method